# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.name

Tags: python, flask

i created this flask blog sort of thing with the help of a youtube tutorial.  i can already create a username etc. but when i try to add name section it gives me this error.

isn't all i need to do these? (i'll fix html stuff later.)
btw when i remove these "name" sections it works without an any error.

this is from users/forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    name=  StringField("name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])

    username = StringField("username", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])

    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField("Şifre", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=50)])

    confirm_password = PasswordField("Şifreyi onayla", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=50), EqualTo("password")])

    submit = SubmitField("Kayıt Ol")
 
    def validate_username(self, username): #database de bu kullunaci varmi onu kontrol ediy
        user= User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("bu kullanici adi daha onceden alinmis.")

    def validate_email(self, email): #database de bu kullunaci varmi onu kontrol ediy
        user= User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("bu email daha onceden kullanilmis.")
```

this is from users/routes.py

```
@users.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"]) #burda methodlari eklemezsek method not allowed error u verecek. tekrar bi bak buna
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8') #form.password.data girilen sifre ilk kismi tekrar check btw.hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash fln.
        user = User(name=form.name.data, username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password) #creating user. user=User()i grasp well.
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Hesabiniz olusturuldu. Giris yapabilirsiniz.', 'success') #success bootstrap seysi
        return redirect(url_for("users.login")) #home burda route daki function un adi
    return render_template("register.html", title="Kayıt Ol", form=form)
```

and this is from users/models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) #primary_key=true a uniqie id for user.....
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False) #string 20 olmasinin nedeni max username.. uniqie olmasi da abvious zati... nulable=false da null olmasini engeller usernamin
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True) #check again
```

Comment: Most probably you need to migrate the database.

Comment: yep thanks i guess that's the problem. though when i db.create_all() it gives me RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. this error. i'm guessing it's probably we switched to blueprints do you know how should i migrate now?

Comment: Create a custom function and push flask application context to it. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/

Alternatively you can use this library: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/